# Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xB6" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8): When uploading files on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, heroku

```
  def upload
    uploaded_io = params[:post][:image]
    File.open(Rails.root.join('app/assets', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'w') do |file|
      file.write(uploaded_io.read)
      params[:post][:image] = uploaded_io.original_filename
    end
  end
```

this is working fine on my development machine on OS X however when running the same cod eon heroku i am getting a 500 error and when i checked the logs this seems to be causing it

```
2012-09-21T16:57:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xB6" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):
2012-09-21T16:57:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:86:in `write'
2012-09-21T16:57:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:86:in `block in upload'
2012-09-21T16:57:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:85:in `open'
2012-09-21T16:57:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:85:in `upload'
2012-09-21T16:57:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:61:in `update'
```

I am clueless as to what to do

Answer (score 0):

I know that has been a long time now, but maybe this can help someonelse:

You could try File.open(Rails.root.join('app/assets', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') (with wb not just w).